# Is negative sampling only used for computational reasons?

Tags: machine-learning, word-embeddings, word2vec

Is negative sampling only used for computational reasons in word2vec and other embedding algorithms? Or are there other benefits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computing the softmax over the entire vocabulary with tens of thousands of words is computationally expensive. With negative sampling, you do not update most of the rows in the output matrix, so you eventually end up with a less accurate estimate of the probability distribution. However, in word2vec you don't care about modeling the distribution of a language model, the only thing you need is to collect training signal that is strong enough to be propagated to the embeddings.