# Why the Transformer model does not require negative sampling but word2vec does?

Tags: natural-language, softmax, word2vec, transformers, negative-sampling

Both [word2vec](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/nlps-word2vec-negative-sampling) and transformer model compute a SOFTMAX function over the words/tokens on the output side.

For word2vec models, [negative sampling](https://www.baeldung.com/cs/nlps-word2vec-negative-sampling) is used for computational reasons:

- [Is negative sampling only used for computational reasons?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/417181/is-negative-sampling-only-used-for-computational-reasons)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/56401065/1516331

So **why don't we use negative sampling for the transformer models as well?**
Is it because:

1. Transformer model was published later than word2vec, so now computational cost of the softmax over the whole vocab is not a big concern;
2. Transformer is an autoregressive model. We need to ensure accurate estimate of the probability distribution as much as possible.

Are these true? Any other reasons?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:
[Why do large LMs use the transpose of the word embeddings matrix in the classification head?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/584685/why-do-large-lms-use-the-transpose-of-the-word-embeddings-matrix-in-the-classifi)

and https://cdn.openai.com/research-covers/language-unsupervised/language_understanding_paper.pdf

From the paper above, you can see that they generate the probability of the token by
applying softmax to the multiplication of output embedding by the transpose of the embedding matrix

h0 = UWe + Wp
hl = transformer_block(hl−1)∀i ∈ [1, n] (2)
P (u) = softmax(hn WeT )

After that you can use cross-entropy loss between P(u) and your label vector for training.

In word2vec the modeling the P(u) has a summation on the denominator (over the vocabulary), most of the approximation techniques are to avoid doing the full sum